# Path-connected, simply connected subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: general-topology

A discussion in my topology class caused me to have the following question:

> Given $A,B \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, where $A$ and $B$ are both path-connected and  simply connected, need $A$ and $B$ be homeomorphic?

I first thought about this in the plane for $A,B\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ and could find no counterexample and did not see the reason why the same should not follow in $\mathbb{R}^n$. How would one go about showing this (or obviously creating a counterexample)?

Comment: How about $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ and $[0,1]\times\{0\}$?

Comment: You'd almost certainly need a hypothesis like open-ness, otherwise there are a lot of counter-examples although I'm not even sure that works (upon quick edit: Riemann mapping +  showing plane is homeomorphic to disc guarantees your claim is true if we suppose $A,B$ open). 

There are $A,B$ satisfying with your criteria with only one compact, only one locally path connected, etc. Or we can find pairs with different topological dimensions.

Comment: Just take $\{ 0 \} $ and $B(0,1)$.

Comment: Such spaces need not even be homotopy equivalent. The *quasi-circle* and a point in $\Bbb R^2$ are both $1$-connected, but the quasi-circle is not contractible.

Comment: You are trying to rediscover what Poincare thought about around the year 1900: What are sufficient conditions for homeomorphism of topological spaces? He first realized the need to restrict to "closed manifolds" (compact and without boundary). Then he realized that simply-connected closed surfaces are all homeomorphic to the 2-sphere (Jordan had "sort of a proof" of this fact, but not up to the modern standards). Then he asked the same about 3-d manifolds. Now, google "Poincare conjecture".

Comment: @Neal This provides a counter example as they both have the properties but deleting a point from the first leaves it path connected while any deletion of a point in the second leaves it not path connected, correct?